# Building PyTorch as a submodule of larger project with Bazel results in invalid file paths

Tags: python, build, bazel

I have a project I need to build using Bazel, and I need the PyTorch libraries for C++. After a lot of trial and error, I've resorted to including PyTorch's source as a submodule. This is because I need to edit the BUILD files and need to specify the dependencies again, since Bazel doesn't read external dependency WORKSPACE files.

The PyTorch build has [this particular python command](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/64f326097be8ac66ff057365f3bed2d64c697563/build.bzl#L126-L131) to generate code. This script has [two hard-coded paths](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/674c104d122797644805b07151850e1dffb10fa2/tools/setup_helpers/generate_code.py#L204-L205) inside, checked with `os.path.isfile`, that I believe are only valid if one executes the PyTorch build from the top of its repo. However, since I'm using PyTorch as a submodule inside my project and running Bazel's build commands from the top of *my* repo, I believe this is causing these paths to not exist. Since this is hard-coded in the source, it feels like I would need to modify the PyTorch submodule itself, but I'd rather not do that. Is there another way?

Comment: The "prefix" is most likely just the *current working directory*, which you can set via `os.chdir()`.

Comment: I understand that, but to do that, I think I would need to modify the Python script of the submodule and I'd rather not do that. If there is a way to set this in the command line, that would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree this is entirely a dupe of the question it's been linked to, but it's impossible to give a more specific answer without the details of exactly what is happening and how. If you want the possibility of a better answer, we'd need a [mre].

Comment: Apologies, added some more context.

Comment: Okay, if I understand your edit correctly, you're including the source code of PyTorch in your project. Forgive me for asking, but is there a reason you need to do that rather than using a separately-built PyTorch as a dependency? You can install "normal" and editable packages into the same environment, if that's at all related.

Comment: I need the PyTorch libraries for C++, and I need to build my project using Bazel. After a lot of trial and error, I've resorted to using PyTorch as a submodule since I need to edit the BUILD files and need to specify the dependencies again, since Bazel doesn't read external dependency WORKSPACE files. If you know of an easier way, I'd be very interested.

Comment: I've edited your question to include the info from both your addendum and your comment. I've never used Bazel and I know little about C++, so it's entirely possible I may not have phrased things 100% correctly when combining and paraphrasing; obviously please feel free to further edit / rollback as needed.